# IExtenderProvider issue with VS2013 WinForms designer

Tags: c#, winforms, iextenderprovider

### **Brief**

I'm implementing IExtenderProvider to provide a property to winforms control to store a collection of permissions per control that must be granted for the control to be available.

### **The problem**

Everything works great as expected, ***the problem is only in design time, and only when***:

1. I open the form designer.
2. Edit permissions (extended property) for some controls on the form.
3. Compile my project while the form designer is open.

then, after compilation, if i try to edit the permissions of the controls again, the permissions are gone, though they are still present in the form's desiger.cs file.

Also, if I, in this state, perform any designer operation that causes regeneration of the designer file e.g. move a button, the permissions are lost from the form's designer file.

*So, as long as i don't compile while the designer is open, everything is OK and i can edit permissions, save and re-edit again.*

**To recover from this state:** *(that is, the permissions are loaded again from designer.cs file)*

- Either close the form designer and re-open it.
- or switch to designer.cs file (while designer still open), and edit anything then undo it, then return to form designer again. It gets refreshed and the permissions are loaded again.

---

### Update 1

Thanks to @Hans Passant for the hint, duh, i was debugging the designer without checking CLR exceptions, thus, exceptions were silently suppressed.

The issue resides in the serializer's Serialize method (refined a bit):

```
public override object Serialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, object value)
{
    CodeDomSerializer baseClassSerializer = manager.GetSerializer(typeof(PermissionExtenderProvider).BaseType, typeof(CodeDomSerializer)) as CodeDomSerializer;
    CodeStatementCollection statements = baseClassSerializer.Serialize(manager, value) as CodeStatementCollection;

    try
    {
        PermissionExtenderProvider provider = (PermissionExtenderProvider)value;
        IDesignerHost host = (IDesignerHost)manager.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
        var components = host.Container.Components.Cast<IComponent>().Where(x => provider.CanExtend(x));
        this.SerializeExtender(manager, provider, host, components, statements);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }

    return statements;
}
```

more specifically, at this line:

```
PermissionExtenderProvider provider = (PermissionExtenderProvider)value;
```

the `value` property is of the same type, which is `PermissionExtenderProvider` but from a different origin (assembly), so the throws the following exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 
[A]VSDesignerExtenderProviderIssue.PermissionExtenderProvider cannot be cast to 
[B]VSDesignerExtenderProviderIssue.PermissionExtenderProvider.
Type A originates from 'VSDesignerExtenderProviderIssue, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ProjectAssemblies\elo5dzxu01\VSDesignerExtenderProviderIssue.exe'. 
Type B originates from 'VSDesignerExtenderProviderIssue, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ProjectAssemblies\5_6og8t_01\VSDesignerExtenderProviderIssue.exe'.
```

Since the problem only occurs after compilation, I think it makes since now.

I'm not exactly sure about the designer process, but my interpretation is that the value is passed from previously compiled assembly, then i try to cast to the same type which reside in the "active" assembly the designer uses, hence the casting cannot be done since the types are from two different assemblies.

*Why does it send the value from a different assembly? is there anyway to work around that without manually mapping/serializing the objects to the types of the active assembly?*

---

### The code

I've tried debugging it in design mode (in the state after compile which is when the problem occurs), but all i can come up with is that the `PermissionExtenderProvider.GetPermissions(...)` method in my extender provider returns `null`, meaning that the `PermissionExtenderProvider.SetPermission(...)` has not been yet called, hence the `PermissionCollectionEditor.EditValue(...)` in my custom UITypeEditor receives the null value and passes it to the `PermissionCollectionEditorForm`, which is why permissions are not there.

I've provided a small sample project that demonstrates the issue, it consists of:

- `Permissions` (folder that contains sample permissions).
- `PermissionCollection`
- `PermissionCollectionEditor` (UITypeEditor implementation).
- `PermissionCollectionEditorForm` (the form that edits the permission collection property).
- `PermissionExtenderProvider` (The IExtenderProvider implementation that provides the `Permission` property).
- `PermissionExtenderProviderSerializer` (The serializer that serializes extended property to designer file.
- `Form1` (the main form of the project, with some buttons with permissions for testing).

You can test the extender with Form1 which has some buttons, and a `PermissionExtenderProvider` instance.

**[Download the sample project](http://1drv.ms/1DRjd7w)**

Here is some key code from the project:

**PermissionCollectionEditor**

```
public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value) 
{
    if (context != null && context.Instance != null && provider != null) 
    {
        var editorService = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));
        if (editorService != null)
        {
            using (PermissionCollectionEditorForm collEditorFrm = new PermissionCollectionEditorForm(provider, value as PermissionCollection))
            {
                if (editorService.ShowDialog(collEditorFrm) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    value = collEditorFrm.Collection;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

**PermissionExtenderProvider**

```
[ProvideProperty("Permissions", typeof(IComponent))]
[DesignerSerializer(typeof(PermissionExtenderProviderSerializer), typeof(CodeDomSerializer))]
public class PermissionExtenderProvider : Component, IExtenderProvider 
{
    private Hashtable _Permissions;
    private bool _InitialVerification = false;
    private List<IComponent> _DisabledComponents;

    public PermissionExtenderProvider()
        : base()
    {
        _Permissions = new Hashtable();
        _DisabledComponents = new List<IComponent>();
    }

    //=====================================
    // IExtenderProvider
    //=====================================
    public bool CanExtend(object extendee)
    {
        return (extendee is Control ||
            extendee is TabPage ||
            extendee is ToolStripItem) && !(extendee is PermissionExtenderProvider);
    }

    //=====================================
    // ProvidedProperties
    //=====================================
    [Category("Behavior")]
    [Editor(typeof(PermissionCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public PermissionCollection GetPermissions(IComponent component)
    {
        PermissionCollection result = null;
        if (_Permissions.ContainsKey(component))
            result = (PermissionCollection)_Permissions[component];

        return result;
    }

    public void SetPermissions(IComponent component, PermissionCollection value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            value = new PermissionCollection();
        }

        if (value.Count == 0)
        {
            _Permissions.Remove(component);
        }
        else
        {
            _Permissions[component] = value;
        }
    }

    //=====================================
    // Permission verification
    //=====================================
    public bool CheckPermissions(IComponent component)
    {
        PermissionCollection permissions = _Permissions.ContainsKey(component) ? (PermissionCollection)_Permissions[component] : null;
        if (permissions == null)
            return false;

        return PermissionProvider.CheckPermissions(permissions.ToArray());
    }        

    public virtual void AssertPermissions(IComponent component)
    {
        bool hasPermission = CheckPermissions(component);

        if(!hasPermission)
        {
            if(component is TabPage)
            {
                ((TabPage)component).Enabled = false;
                ((TabControl)((TabPage)component).Parent).Invalidate();
            }
            else if(component is ToolStripItem)
            {
                ((ToolStripItem)component).Enabled = false;
            }
            else if(component is Control)
            {
                ((Control)component).Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        // Add/Remove to the list of disabled components
        if(hasPermission && _DisabledComponents.Contains(component))
        {
            _DisabledComponents.Remove(component);
        }
        else if(!hasPermission && !_DisabledComponents.Contains(component))
        {
            _DisabledComponents.Add(component);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Verify the permissions associated with the control provider. It hides/disables the controls
    /// associated if the all or any of the permissions are not granted (depending on options specified for the control)
    /// </summary>
    public virtual void VerifyPermissions()
    {
        _DisabledComponents.Clear();

        // Verify the permissions
        foreach (IComponent comp in _Permissions.Keys)
        {
            AssertPermissions(comp);
        }
    }

    //================================================
    // Wiring the host container's load event
    //================================================
    private ContainerControl m_Host;

    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public ContainerControl Host
    {
        get { return m_Host; }
        set
        {
            if (m_Host == null && value as Form != null && !DesignMode)
            {
                (value as Form).Load += Initialize;
            }
            else if (m_Host == null && value as UserControl != null && !DesignMode)
            {
                (value as UserControl).Load += Initialize;
            }
            m_Host = value;
        }
    }

    private void Initialize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!DesignMode)
        {
            VerifyPermissions();
            _InitialVerification = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**PermissionExtenderProviderSerializer**

```
    public class PermissionExtenderProviderSerializer : CodeDomSerializer
{
    public override object Serialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, object value)
    {
        PermissionExtenderProvider provider = value as PermissionExtenderProvider;

        CodeDomSerializer baseClassSerializer = manager.GetSerializer(typeof(PermissionExtenderProvider).BaseType, typeof(CodeDomSerializer)) as CodeDomSerializer;
        CodeStatementCollection statements = baseClassSerializer.Serialize(manager, value) as CodeStatementCollection;

        IDesignerHost host = (IDesignerHost)manager.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost));
        ComponentCollection components = host.Container.Components;

        this.SerializeExtender(manager, provider, host, components, statements);

        return statements;
    }

    private void SerializeExtender(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, PermissionExtenderProvider provider, IDesignerHost host, ComponentCollection components, CodeStatementCollection statements)
    {
        if (components.Count > 0)
        {
            statements.Add(new CodeCommentStatement(" "));
            statements.Add(new CodeCommentStatement(manager.GetName(provider)));
            statements.Add(new CodeCommentStatement(" "));
        }

        // Set the Host property of the provider, this is where we wire the Load event to assert permissions
        statements.Add(new CodeSnippetStatement(string.Format("this.{0}.Host = this;", manager.GetName(provider))));

        // Serialize permissions for components
        foreach (IComponent component in components)
        {
            if (component is PermissionExtenderProvider
                || component == host.RootComponent)
            {
                continue;
            }

            PropertyDescriptor descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(component)["Name"];
            if (descriptor != null)
            {
                CodeMethodInvokeExpression methodcall = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(base.SerializeToExpression(manager, provider), "SetPermissions");
                string extendeeName = descriptor.GetValue(component).ToString();
                methodcall.Parameters.Add(new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), extendeeName));

                PermissionCollection permissions = provider.GetPermissions(component);
                if (permissions != null && permissions.Count > 0)
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    // Create new PermissionCollection instance and supply permissions array to constructor
                    sb.Append("new PermissionCollection(");
                    sb.Append("new ");
                    sb.Append(typeof(IPermission).FullName);
                    sb.Append("[] {");

                    foreach (IPermission perm in permissions)
                    {
                        PropertyInfo operationEnumProperty = perm.GetType()
                            .GetProperty("Operation");

                        object operationTypeVal = operationEnumProperty.GetValue(perm, null);
                        string operationTypeEnumValName = Enum.GetName(operationEnumProperty.PropertyType, operationTypeVal);

                        sb.AppendLine();
                        sb.Append("new ");
                        sb.Append(perm.GetType().FullName);
                        sb.Append("(");
                        sb.Append(perm.GetType().FullName);
                        sb.Append(".OperationType.");
                        sb.Append(operationTypeEnumValName);
                        sb.Append(")");
                        sb.Append(", ");
                    }

                    // Remove trailing comma from last item
                    if (permissions.Count > 0)
                    {
                        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 2, 2);
                    }

                    sb.Append(" })");

                    methodcall.Parameters.Add(new CodeSnippetExpression(sb.ToString()));

                }
                else
                {
                    methodcall.Parameters.Add(new CodePrimitiveExpression(null));
                }

                statements.Add(methodcall);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### **Background info from initial post**

I have a winforms app, with intermediate service layer to interact with the database.

In the database, i have tables that define and map permissions to users and user roles. those permissions are represented in classes in my application, and implement `IPermission`.

In my application, i have a `PermissionProvider` class that calls the service and checks for permissions of the user to disable/hide any controls that the user do not have to access (and of course, i do not rely on this for security).

What i wanted to do is, extend Winforms controls by adding `Permissions` property, which is a permission collection, so i used `IExtenderProvider`.

I've implemented my custom `UITypeEditor` to edit the property, and custom [CodeDomSerializer](http://www.timvw.be/2007/08/21/bending-the-code-generation-of-iextenderprovider-to-your-will/) to serialize the permission collection properly in the designer file.

I have also added a property called `Host` in my extender provider which stores the form/user control hosting the provider, and it's serialized in designer file  by my custom serializer along with permissions.

Then in my provider, when the`Host` property is set, i subscribe to the `Load` event of the host form/user control, and verify the permissions of the controls when the host is loaded at runtime, and put a small indicator so the user knows that the control has been disabled due to insufficient permissions.

I'm running VS2013 Community with Update 4, Win 8.1 64-bit, and compiling in x86.

Comment: I don't have any answers but I can say good luck, I've struggled through serialization issues in the designer myself and it was not a fun process. I found out that removing custom serialization code and letting the designer "do its thing" helped, so I'd start taking things apart until it behaves then try to add things back in (even if its serializing to the resx file).

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks, i've been already trying different things, and faced multiple issues until i came up with this serialization format that i "thought" the designer is happy with, obviously it's not, to some extent.

Comment: I'm going to have to take a vacation to read it all.  Punting: exceptions at design-time cause this kind of behavior.  Start another instance of VS, Tools + Attach to Process to attach to the first instance of VS.  Debug > Exceptions > tick CLR exceptions to see them.

Comment: @HansPassant I've tried to shorten it. And duh, i was debugging without checking CLR exceptions hence the exceptions were suppressed. Thanks for the hint.

After debugging, i came up with something, and updated the question.

Comment: @HansPassant Any idea why does the designer passes the value from a different assembly?